# Find distance of character from middle of string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to write a function that takes a word and letter and finds the distance of that letter from the center of the string (only the first occurrence, I'll iterate the function).

For words with odd numbers of letters, I can write

```
if (word.indexOf(letter) !== -1 && word.length % 2 == 1) {
  dist = absoluteValOf(Math.floor(word.length / 2) - word.indexOf(letter));
}
```

But for even strings, I want to count the middle two characters as the middle (i.e. the 'a' in rabbit is 1 away from the middle). Is there a good general solution?

Comment: can u give an example input/output to help clarify what you want?

Comment: Yes, you would pass the func a word and a letter (e.g. 'rabbit' and 'a') and it would return the distance of the index from the center for the first occurrence of the letter. So, rabbit and a would return 1, so would rabbit and i. Bunny and u would return 1, but bunny and b would return 2. Does that make sense? Thanks

Comment: To try to clarify the point about words with even numbers of letters, the middle 2 letters are being counted as one for the purpose of the calculation, so the word can be treated as "r  a  bb  i  t"

Comment: What about `evening` and `e`?

Comment: `evening` and `e` would return 3, because it looks for the only the first occurence. I replace the character with a `%` and iterate to get the values of remaining characters (though I would welcome a better solution!)

Comment: can the word have space(s) in it ?

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why your current code snippet doesn't work for you (other than replacing `absoluteValOf` with `Math.abs`) ? I get the expected results with your bunny examples

Comment: @Alp I strip out spaces   Crayon letters in the second half of the word wouldn't give the right value (thanks for the function!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a problem because [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method is zero based, while string length starts from 1. You can annul it this way:

```js
function distance(ch, str) {
    return Math.floor(Math.abs((str.length-1)/2-str.indexOf(ch)));
};
console.log(distance('b', 'Rabbit'));
console.log(distance('t', 'Rabbit'));
console.log(distance('u', 'Bunny'));
console.log(distance('y', 'Bunny'));
```

Explanation: we reduce string length by one and than divide to find the middle comparing to `indexOf` value. For 6 letters word we get matrix:

```
[2.5, 1.5, .5, -.5, -1.5, -2.5]
```

and for 5 letters word we get:

```
[2, 1, 0, -1, -2]
```

which is a **real distance** from the middle. Now we just need to `floor` absolute values, because you wanted character(s) in middle to have zero distance (otherwise we would `Math.ceil` them and 'b' in 'Rabbit' would have distance 1).

Answer (score 2):

You have to check whether the index of the searched letter is in the first or last half of the word itself. Then:

If it is in the first half, the distance is 
`dist = Math.abs((word.length / 2) -1) - word.indexOf(letter));`

If it is in the last half, the distance is
`dist = Math.abs((word.length / 2) - word.indexOf(letter));`

```js
var word='rabbit';
var letter='a';
var dist=0;
if (word.indexOf(letter) !== -1) {
    if(word.indexOf(letter)<word.length/2)
      dist = Math.abs(Math.floor(word.length / 2)-1 - word.indexOf(letter));
    else
        dist = Math.abs((word.length / 2) - word.indexOf(letter));
}
console.log(dist);
```